# php why is isset always true even if fields don't contain anything?

Tags: php

I'm trying to save values of checkboxes in Wordpress. The Problem I'm facing is simple, `if( isset( $used_checkboxes_csv ) )` always returns true even if no checkbox has been selected thus always creates DB entry. Any ideas how to resolve this or what to use instead of isset?

```
//Listing details features and services meta checkboxes
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_checklist_add' );
function cd_meta_checklist_add() {add_meta_box( 'checklist-id', 'Listing Icons', 'cd_meta_checklist_cb', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );}

function cd_meta_checklist_cb() 
{ 

        global $post;
        $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );

        //check of checkbox should be active or not
        $pricelistline = explode(",", get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_features_checklist', true));

        // We'll use this nonce field later on when saving.
        wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );

?>

        <p>
            <label for="meta_box_check_bar">bar</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="meta_box_check_bar" name="meta_box_check_bar" value="bar" <?php if ($pricelistline[0]) {echo "checked";} ?> />
        </p>
        <p> 
            <label for="meta_box_check_parking">parking</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="meta_box_check_parking" name="meta_box_check_parking" value="parking" <?php if ($pricelistline[1]) {echo "checked";} ?> />
        </p>
        <p> 
            <label for="meta_box_check_accessible-for-disabled">accessible-for-disabled</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="meta_box_check_accessible-for-disabled" name="meta_box_check_accessible-for-disabled" value="accessible-for-disabled" <?php if ($pricelistline[2]) {echo "checked";} ?> />
        </p>
        <p> 
            <label for="meta_box_check_air-conditioning">air-conditioning</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="meta_box_check_air-conditioning" name="meta_box_check_air-conditioning" value="air-conditioning" <?php if ($pricelistline[3]) {echo "checked";} ?> />
        </p>
        <p> 
            <label for="meta_box_check_frigo-bar">frigo-bar </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="meta_box_check_frigo-bar" name="meta_box_check_frigo-bar" value="frigo-bar" <?php if ($pricelistline[4]) {echo "checked";} ?> />
        </p>
        <p> 
            <label for="meta_box_check_pets">pets</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="meta_box_check_pets" name="meta_box_check_pets" value="pets" <?php if ($pricelistline[5]) {echo "checked";} ?> />
        </p>
        <p> 
            <label for="meta_box_check_phone">phone</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="meta_box_check_phone" name="meta_box_check_phone" value="phone" <?php if ($pricelistline[6]) {echo "checked";} ?> />
        </p>
        <p> 
            <label for="meta_box_check_tv">tv</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="meta_box_check_tv" name="meta_box_check_tv" value="tv" <?php if ($pricelistline[7]) {echo "checked";} ?> />
        </p>
        <p> 
            <label for="meta_box_check_local-dishes">local-dishes</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="meta_box_check_local-dishes" name="meta_box_check_local-dishes" value="local-dishes" <?php if ($pricelistline[8]) {echo "checked";} ?> />
        </p>
<?php }

//Saving checkbox states
add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_checkbox_save' );  
function cd_meta_checkbox_save( $post_id )  
{  
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save  
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return; 

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail 
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return; 

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail  
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;


    //grabing all checkbox values and combining them

                                /* make an array for all used checkbox */
                                $used_checkboxes = array();

                                /* make an array whit all options */
                                $avaible_checkboxes = explode(',', "bar,parking,accessible-for-disabled,air-conditioning,frigo-bar,pets,phone,tv,local-dishes");


                                /* loop troguht all avaible checkboxes */
                                foreach($avaible_checkboxes as $current_key)
                                {
                                   /* check if the checkbox was sent */
                                   if(isset($_POST["meta_box_check_{$current_key}"]))
                                   {
                                      /* if sent, add key to list */
                                      $used_checkboxes[$current_key] = $current_key;
                                   }
                                   else
                                   {
                                      /* if not sent, add empty value to list */
                                      $used_checkboxes[$current_key] = '';
                                   }
                                }

                                /* convert list to csv */
                                $used_checkboxes_csv = implode(',', $used_checkboxes);


    //saving to DB
    if( isset( $used_checkboxes_csv ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_features_checklist', esc_attr( $used_checkboxes_csv ) );


}
```

Comment: @2astalavista yes, why would there be problem with that? its closing of a function.

Comment: I see. It just made confused the syntax highlighter (and me)

Comment: @2astalavista :) copy paste from functions.php its just a part of the file, sorry about it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null and/or empty strings are still set if the variable is declared. Try this:

```
if(isset($used_checkboxes_csv ) && $used_checkboxes_csv == 'somevalue')
```

Comment: if ($used_checkboxes_csv != ',,,,,,,,,') this could work right?

Comment: Actually, `isset()` returns `FALSE` for variables that have a `NULL` value.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I meant empty strings. As booleans default to FALSE, integers and floats default to zero, strings (e.g. used in echo) are set as an empty string and arrays become to an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use `empty` which checks if a variable has anything in it or potentially `is_null` which checks whether a variable is set to null.

In terms of your code:

```
$used_checkboxes = array();
// You SET the variable here

if( isset( $used_checkboxes_csv ) )
// So the isset function will return true

// To remove empty elements in an array, you can do this in your implode statement:
implode(',', array_filter($used_checkboxes));
```

[Empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
<?php
$expected_array_got_string = 'somestring';
var_dump(empty($expected_array_got_string['some_key']));
var_dump(empty($expected_array_got_string[0]));
var_dump(empty($expected_array_got_string['0']));
var_dump(empty($expected_array_got_string[0.5]));
var_dump(empty($expected_array_got_string['0.5']));
var_dump(empty($expected_array_got_string['0 Mostel']));
?>

Output of the above example in PHP 5.3:

bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)

Output of the above example in PHP 5.4:

bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

[is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$foo = NULL;
var_dump(is_null($inexistent), is_null($foo));

?>

Notice: Undefined variable: inexistent in ...
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Comment: No, empty will return always true, because I do this: implode(',', $used_checkboxes); which creates empty commas ,,,,, when checkboxes are not set. When they are set it creates ,,,bar,,, for example. So empty will not work. Cause it is not 'empty'.

Comment: You can use `array_filter($used_checkboxes)` to get rid of any empty cells (as long as nothing else in there evaluates to false. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the variable here:

```
$used_checkboxes_csv = implode(',', $used_checkboxes);
```

Regardless of whether it has the correct content or not, it IS set because it DOES exist.

This means that:

```
if( isset( $used_checkboxes_csv ) )
```

Will always return true.

What you could do is this:

```
$used_checkboxes_csv = NULL;
if( count($used_checkboxes) > 0){
    $used_checkboxes_csv = implode(',', $used_checkboxes);
}
```

Then, check it this way:

```
if( strlen($used_checkboxes_csv) > 0 ){
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, $used_checkboxes_csv will contain minimum ,,,,, or will contain ,,,bar,, how do I make check for this? ,,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Because the $_POST contains empty string for your value, and isset() returns true. Use empty() or add != '' in your if condition.